# How to correctly fork and finish process to avoid EAGAIN error

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I need to fork many short life processes. (But I don't want to wait until it is finished. Just let it run.). After some time, I receive error when executing fork (errno == 11). It looks like the forked processes still exists (at least they are visible in htop).

For instance, please consider the following example. I want to fork a process and then exit it shortly after.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

void RunProc(){   
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        puts("fork with success");
        //no needed to reproduce issue. Used in my code to run some commands.
        //execvp()             
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid == -1) {
        printf("Could not start process\n");
        printf("Errno: %d\n", errno);
    }
    else {
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    while(true){
        RunProc();
    }

    int res = 0;
    int i = 5;
    res = scanf("%d", &i);
    res = printf("End of program %d\n", i);
    return res;
}
```

At the beginning it runs correctly. After several minutes I receive only errors:

> Could not start process
> Errno: 11

And I'm not able to start new fork anymore.
I'm running it on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: On an unrelated issue: You should really be using [`_exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) to exit child processes. The `exit` function might cause problems for the parent process.

Comment: Your process spawns a herd of zombies. Make double fork to allow init process reap them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call one of [the `wait` functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) in the parent process, to reap the child-process when it exits.

You could use e.g. `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag to poll for child-process exit. Or use the `SIGCHLD` signal to learn when a child process have exited.

There's only a limited number of process-slots available in your system, if you don't reap the child processes, they will fill up all the slots and lead to the error you get.

As [the `fork` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) say about the `EAGAIN` error:

> A system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.

Comment: Thanks. I was testing several options. I can maintain forked pids to wait only on those forked. But adding such loop before forking new ones also resolves the issue. There will be 1 fork not closed but it shouldn't be a problem. `int wstatus; while(waitpid(-1, &wstatus, WNOHANG) > 0);`

Answer (score 1):

When process terminates, its PID and exit status still remains as a record in  process table. This is so called zombie process. You can remove it by reading its status with one of `wait()` functions family, as described in sibling answer.

If you don't need to care about status of child processes, you can allow `init` to read their status and cleanup the table. When parent process terminates, `init` (process with PID 1) becomes parent of all its children processes by default. Thus you can use double fork to make `init` to be a parent of your processes:

```c
void RunProc(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork()");
        return;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // first level child
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork()");
            _exit(1);
        }
        if (pid != 0) {
            // first level child just terminates
            _exit(0);
        }

        // second level child
        puts("fork with success");

        _exit(0);
    }

    // wait for first level child
    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("wait()");
    }
}
```